# Extract part of pasting html in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor for my asp.net mvc (C#) application.

I need to extract a part of html before pasting to the CKEditor.

For Ex, i have the following html ready to be pasted to CKEditor:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Dummy Content
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0" id="tabletocopy" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Actual Content
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to copy only the html of the table "`tabletocopy`", not the entire(including body) html, something like:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" id="tabletocopy" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
      <td>
         Actual Content
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I found the [paste event](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event:paste) of CKEditor, but i am not sure on how to use this for my need.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On paste event, you will get the html in `e.data.html` as described in [link](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event%3apaste).

In that event you can extract the html using jquery.

```
e.data.html = $(e.data.html).find("#tabletocopy").html();
```

Comment: Wow, this is cool, but a small change as for my need to get the html including table:

ev.data.html = $('<div>').append($(ev.data.html).find("#tabletocopy").clone()).remove().html();

Comment: Mevada thanks for the link, it will prove useful in a short time for me :)